# Help with Visualforce Email Template

Tags: html5, visualforce-template

When we create an opportunity we create a certain number of quotes (custom, child record).  I would like to be able to send an email to include information from all the quotes created under the opportunity.This is my first visualforce email template. I want to be able to pull   I need some help because when I go to save I receive the following errors:

> Error: VF_Test line 31, column 27: XML document structures must start
>   and end within the same entity     Error: XML document structures must
>   start and end within the same entity.

My Email Content:

```
<messaging:emailTemplate recipientType="User"
                     relatedToType="Opportunity"
                     subject=" {!Opportunity.Account}, {!Quotes_RFR__c.Current_Carrier__c}, {!Opportunity.Date_Due__c},{!Opportunity.Total_Eligible__c}" >
<messaging:htmlEmailBody >  
    <html>
        <body>
            <STYLE type="text/css">
                TH {font-size: 11px; font-face: arial;background: #CCCCCC; border-width: 1;  text-align: center } 
                TD  {font-size: 11px; font-face: verdana } 
                TABLE {border: solid #CCCCCC; border-width: 1}
                TR {border: solid #CCCCCC; border-width: 1}
            </STYLE>
            <font face="arial" size="2">
                <table border="0" >
                    <tr > 
                        th><th>Quote Number</th><th>Contribution Type</th><th>In Network</th><th>Out of Network</th>
                    </tr>
                    <apex:repeat var="cx" value="{!Quotes_RFR__c}">
                        <tr>
                            <td>{!Quotes_RFR__c.Quote_Name__c} </td>
                            <td>{!Quotes_RFR__c.Contribution_Type__c}</td>
                            <td>{!Quotes_RFR__c.In_NetworkDiag_Prev__c}/ {!NullValue(Quotes_RFR__c.In_Network_Basic__c, "0")}/ {!NullValue(Quotes_RFR__c.In_Network_Major__c, "0")}/ {!NullValue(Quotes_RFR__c.In_Network_Ortho__c, "0")}; {!Quotes_RFR__c.In_Network_Deductible_Ind__c}/ {!Quotes_RFR__c.In_Network_Deductible_Fam__c} Ded; {!Quotes_RFR__c.In_Network_Annual_Max__c} Max; {!NullValue(Quotes_RFR__c.In_Network_Ortho_Max__c, "0")}</td>
                            <td>{!Quotes_RFR__c.Out_Network_Diag_Prev__c}/ {!NullValue(Quotes_RFR__c.Out_Network_Basic__c, "0")}/ {!NullValue(Quotes_RFR__c.Out_Network_Major__c, "0")}/ {!NullValue(Quotes_RFR__c.Out_Network_Ortho__c, "0")}; {!Quotes_RFR__c.Out_Network_Deductible_Ind__c}/ {!Quotes_RFR__c.Out_Network_Deductible_Fam__c} Ded; {!Quotes_RFR__c.Out_Network_Annual_Max__c} Max; {!NullValue(Quotes_RFR__c.Out_Network_Ortho_Max__c, "0")} </td>
                        </tr>
                    </apex:repeat>                 
                </table>
                <p />
            </font>
        </body>
    </html>
</messaging:htmlEmailBody>
```

Comment: Sorry, it cut off the end of it:

Comment: I don't think `<p>` is a valid self closing tag... You also have a seeming typo as your header row leads off with `th>`.

Comment: @Michelle: Are you sure this is the complete code? If yes, could you try adding `</messaging:emailTemplate >` at the end?

Comment: @shailesh that could be issue. You can maybe add it as an answer. You beat me to it by few seconds :D

Comment: @ShaileshPatil I added that at the end and the error message now reads: Unknown property 'core.email.template.EmailTemplateController.Opportunity'

Comment: I think the issue has to do with the references to Quotes_RFR__c. You are trying to reference a field that you don't have direct access to from the opportunity. If that is a referenced custom field under an opportunity, maybe try using {!Opportunity.Quotes_RFR__r.Current_Carrier__c} (for example)

Comment: looking at the master detail relationship field on the quote object it has the API name as Opportunity__c.  Do you think I should use that?

Answer (score 0):

The issue is most likely on your repeat

```
<apex:repeat var="cx" value="{!Quotes_RFR__c}">
```

You will need

```
<apex:repeat var="cx" value="{!relatedTo.Quotes_RFR__r}">
```

`relatedTo` to bind to the target object used by the VF Email Template (i.e. an Opportunity) and `Quotes_RFR__r` which is the relationship name from Opportunity to the custom Quote object. (I'm making an assumption here on your names, but it will definitely end in `__r`)